# Why would this stop working without any changes being made to it?

Tags: php, email, gmail

It's been working perfectly for at least 4 years, but within the last month the emails it is supposed to send don't arrive. Similar posts do NOT have the answer I'm looking for.

- Zero changes have been made to the file in 4 years
- The PHP version on the server is 7.2
- GoDaddy rep. insists no changes have been made to the server, but might have been incompetent.

Does anyone know of any protocols that might've changed (maybe for gmail, but I tried a yahoo account as well) just this year?
Should I try updating the PHP version to 8.1?

```
<?php
//REPORT ALL PHP ERRORS
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function mailcheck($field) {
  $field = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  if(!filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    return FALSE;
  } else {
    return TRUE;
  }
}

function checkInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if(isset($_POST['gName'])) {
    $mailcheck = mailcheck($_POST['gEmail']);

    if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
        echo json_encode("Invalid email");
    } else {
        $gName = checkInput($_POST['gName']);
        $gEmail = checkInput($_POST['gEmail']);
        $gComments = checkInput($_POST['gComments']);

        $mBody = "SENT BY - ".$gName."\n";
        $mBody .= "SENDER EMAIL - ".$gEmail."\n";
        $mBody .= "RATING - ".$_POST['gRating']."\n\n";
        $mBody .= "MESSAGE - ".$gComments."\n";

        if (mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Guest Review', $mBody, 'From: '.$gEmail)) {
            echo json_encode("Review sent. Thank You!");
        } else {
            echo json_encode("Error. Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can they check the mail logs on the server to see if it's sending?

Comment: `'From: '.$gEmail` - that is a very bad idea, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436/1427878, section titled "Don't use a faux `From:` sender"

Comment: I finally got a competent rep. on the phone. Turns out they're getting declined from gmail due to DMARC Policy. Now at least I have some jumping off point for a new headache.

Weirdly enough, I've never had issues using the sender's email as 'From' and this form's been running for years. But thanks, I know it's contraindicated. (I did, of course, hardcode it to a same-domain email for troubleshooting purposes, in addition to trying a yahoo email for recipient.)